# Integrate Qt application in PHP

Tags: php, c++, qt, php-extension

I'm working with C++, using QtCreator. For some reasons I need to use my project in the web (server side). I think there is a way to make extensions for PHP with C++ and Qt.

So, the question is: can I use my project with PHP?, and how can I do this?

Comment: Be more specific. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to use all my project in the web; I've made a parser in C++ and I want to use some functions using PHP. I'm using Qt 5.1.1.